# Crop uiimage as screen size

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage, crop

My application have an function that allow user to move and scale the image just like setting allowsEditing = YES with UIImagePickerController.

My approach is having a scrollview which allow user to zoom with level 1-4
There is only a image view on the scrollview.

At the end, I want to crop the image as the screen size. How can I do it?

Comment: For you if you want to crop the image, go to the photo>>click the photo u like to crop then press on/off switch and home button that image will become save us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to capture the layer of the view containing the scaled / rotated image. In this case you need to capture the scrollview layer NOT the image itself.

I have a UIImage capture category for this...check out [my article and download the source code.](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/how-categories-can-simplify-your-code/)

**UPDATE:** to crop part of the image as per the comment below...

First capture the whole view then crop the image to the specified rect using the following method in the `UIImage+Resize` category (also in the article...)

```
- (UIImage *)croppedImage:(CGRect)bounds;
```

Comment: okay simon lee using this how to implement the resize like-http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/8930/customcropbox.jpg, can you guide me

Comment: Thanks Simon, I got the idea. I capture the layer of the scrollview. But the problem is that when I zoom in and render the layer out, the result screen is shifted with white space. Should I record the offset or the zoom scale to get the right output image?

Comment: You should use the content offset property of the scroll view to determine where the rect starts (x and y) and then the scrollview width and height for the size.

Comment: upvoted you, how to call the uiimage+resize method to crop the image, pleas help,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238464/croping-an-uiimage-using-frame-to-cut/8238674#8238674

Comment: It is a category so it means you are adding that method to the existing UIImage class. This means you can call [myImage croppedImage:CGRectMake(100, 200, 50, 25)]; this will take a crop of the image at 100 pixels across, 200 down and a size of 50x25px.

Comment: i want my  crop should be dynamic , could u please help me, as i shown in the above jpg format

Comment: Just use the frame of the sub view (the cropping rectangle).

Comment: sorry but I am using it and it is zooming my image and cropping.